# PL/SQL Statment ignored

Tags: functions, plsql

I am really new in PL/SQL and I stuck over here. I want to write function which return `allProject`

```
create or replace FUNCTION GETALLPROJECTS RETURN VARCHAR2 AS 
  currentUserID varchar2(10);
BEGIN
 SELECT
   p.ProjectID,
   p.CustomName,
   p.Name,
   p.Responsible_person_id,
   p.Delivery_contact,
   p.StartDate,
   p.EndDate,
   p.TehnicReview,
   p.status
 INTO currentUserID  
FROM
   projects p
LEFT JOIN
   project_users_schedule_dates pusd
ON
    pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND 
    pusd.UserID = currentUserID
LEFT JOIN 
    responsible_persons rp
ON 
    rp.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND 
    rp.UserID = currentUserID
LEFT JOIN 
   users u
ON 
   u.UserID = currentUserID
 WHERE
  u.User_roleID = 1
OR 
(
   (p.Responsible_person_id := currentUserID OR 
    p.Delivery_contact = currentUserID OR 
    rp.UserID = currentUserID OR 
   (pusd.ProjectID = p.ProjectID AND                         
   pusd.UserID = currentUserID AND NOW() BETWEEN pusd.StartDate AND pusd.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY 
   AND
   NOW() BETWEEN p.StartDate AND p.EndDate + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
   AND p.status = 2))
GROUP BY 
    p.ProjectID
 ORDER BY 
    p.ProjectID 
  RETURN currentUserID;
END GETALLPROJECTS;
```

I get error messages which I dont understand what problem is:

```
Error(4,1): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Error(25,16): PL/SQL: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: What does the row `currentUserID varchar2(10);` is supposed to mean? `DECLARE` is lost... How do you want to assign 9 column values into one variable `currentUserID` in your SELECT ?

Comment: Column currentUserID is coumn in table UserID and I want to pass UserID to get data. 
What do you mean by assign 9 column to one variable ? is it possible or not ? If not, what is better way to create something like this ?

Comment: Parameters declaration is placed immediately after procedure name and is wrapped with parenthesis. Study [CREATE PROCEDURE Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_procedure.htm#LNPLS01373). *What do you mean by assign 9 column to one variable ?* You use `SELECT columns_list INTO variables_list ...`. columns_list contains 9 column names, variables_list contains single variable name.

Comment: What do you suggest to avoid this store 9 column in one variable ?

Comment: Something like `CREATE FUNCTION proc_name (currentUserID varchar2(10)) RETURNS table_type AS BEGIN RETURN (SELECT columns FROM joined_source_tables WHERE sometable.UserID = currentUserID  AND another_conditions); END proc_name;`

Comment: The problem here is that I need to create a function from belowe `query` and result need to be save from SELECT statment and Function which I create

Comment: [CREATE FUNCTION Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_function.htm#LNPLS01370).

Comment: Oracle has no `now()` function and `INTERVAL 1 DAY` should be `INTERVAL '1' DAY`. But you could simply use `sysdate + 1` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with a simplified example, as that whole complicated query doesn't seem to be part of the problem.

```
create or replace function demo
    return varchar2
as
    somevar varchar2(1);
begin
    select dummy into somevar
    from   dual;
    
    return somevar;
end demo;
```

This queries the `dual` table, fetches the value of column `dummy` into local variable `somevar`, and returns it as the result of the function.

Now we can test it:

```
declare
    testvar varchar2(1) := demo();
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Result is: '||testvar);
end;
/

Result is: X
```

If you want to retrieve two columns using `select into`, you'll need two variables to hold the two results. However, the function can only return one value so I can't see any point in doing that.

```
create or replace function demo
    return number
as
    somevar1 varchar2(1);
    somevar2 number;
begin
    select dummy, ascii(dummy) into somevar1, somevar2
    from   dual;
    
    return somevar2;
end demo;
```

However, you mentioned at the top:

> I want to write function which return `allProject`

What is `allProject`?

If you want to return a result set, then return that:

```
create or replace function demo
    return sys_refcursor
as
    results sys_refcursor;
begin
    open results for
        select dummy
        from   dual;
    
    return results;
end demo;
```

Or, you could return the results as a collection (this is known as table function).

Which of these approaches is best will depend on what `allProject` is and how you need to use it.